# python Agregar variable para guardar un archivo

Tags: python

Tengo el siguiente código. Arroja error cuando quiero guardar el archivo con la variable fecha.
Como debo agregar la variable para que pueda modificar el nombre del archivo

```
#Renombrar archivo
src=r'D:\pam.txt'
des=r'D:\**'+fecha+'**pam.txt'
os.replace(src,des)
```

Answer (score 1):

No entiendo qué tratas de hacer con los `**`. En Windows el `*` es un caracter ilegal en el nombre de archivo o una ruta. Son utilizados como comodines para hacer búsquedas desde el sistema.

Ver [Caracteres reservados](https://learn.microsoft.com/es-es/windows/win32/fileio/naming-a-file#naming-conventions) para nombres de archivo en Windows

```py
>>> src = r'D:\pam.txt'
>>> fecha = '2022-12-02'
>>> dest = r'D:\**' + fecha + '**pam.txt'
>>> print(dest)
'D:\**2022-12-02**pam.txt' # <-- No es un nombre de archivo válido
>>> os.replace(src, des)
OSError: [WinError 123] The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect
```

Corrigiendo lo de los `*` y lo de [concatenar](https://stackoverflow.com/q/55514823/1545868) un *r'string'* con la fecha:

```py
>>> des = r'D:\{}pam.txt'.format(fecha)
>>> os.replace(src, des)
>>> # <-- Correcto
```